# Customize android ViewPager with additional views -- as component

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-navigation

I would like to have a customized ViewPager, augmented with additional views that have specific behavior depending on interaction with the ViewPager.

I have implemented all I want, adding views to the main layout that holds the ViewPager and all the other views. Then adding the logic to the existing ViewPager, adding custom listeners etc...

It works BUT... It's ugly – code that is responsible for managing the behavior of the viewpager is "leaked" to the activity that holds the layout containing the ViewPager and the other views (no encapsulation) AND the more severe problem is – this is absolutely not reusable.

So I wanted to extend the ViewPager and add all the extra views and the logic into the ViewPager itself and make it an encapsulated, reusable component. ViewPager extends ViewGroup so I thought I'd add views that I want and be all set - but once I add views – they do not show up and I don't know why.

Here's the code I tried (ignore the name of the class)

```
public class ClickableViewPager extends ViewPager {


/**
 * @param context
 */
public ClickableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.initViews(context);
}



/**
 * @param context
 * @param attrs
 */
public ClickableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.initViews(context);

}


private void initViews(Context context) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);


    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("BLAH");


    this.addView(tv);

    this.addView(iv);
}
```

Comment: A `ViewPager` holds pages. It does not hold arbitrary other stuff. You will need to wrap the `ViewPager` and your other views in some outer container (e.g., `LinearLayout`).

Comment: This is what I sort of came to a conclusion but it just doesn't feel right... :(

Comment: Remember that `ViewGroup` is largely an abstraction. While a `ViewGroup` knows about having child widgets, it takes a subclass of `ViewGroup` to implement layout rules. `ViewPager`'s layout rules are tied into `PagerAdapter` and not arbitrary child widgets.